# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

Wherever I click, I am getting this loading image, and I am unable to add new categories and products in Magento 2.2.0

[image: Loading Image Screenshot]

This is the error that I keep getting in the console

```
Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
at setRootListener (async.js:132)
at Object.<anonymous> (jquery.js:3411)
at fire (jquery.js:3232)
at Object.add [as done] (jquery.js:3291)
at Array.<anonymous> (jquery.js:3410)
at Function.each (jquery.js:370)
at Object.<anonymous> (jquery.js:3406)
at Function.Deferred (jquery.js:3472)
at Object.then (jquery.js:3405)
at Function.$.async (async.js:183)
```